# Knockout Viewmodel advice (multiple binding failure)

Tags: knockout.js

I have some things I need to store as observables in my app. I've tried creating separate veiwmodels but when I bind them it clears the others.  So I'm just going to post what my basic data layout is and see if anyone is willing to suggest a way to define the viewmodels...

- Search Results

  - Result Name
  - Result Type
- Items

  - Item Name
  - Type
  - properties

    - Property Name
    - Property Value
- More?

The biggest trick is that I'm trying to bind each item to a dynamically created element like so:

```
    $("<div/>", {                                                       //create new div
        class: "itemView",                                              //add css class
        id: name,                                                       //set ID to item name (may change to array location later?)
        "data-bind": "template: { name: 'tmplItemView' }"
    }).appendTo("body").draggable();                                    //append to the body and make it draggable
    items[numItems] = new item();
    ko.applyBindings(items[numItems], 
        document.getElementById('#' + name));
```

I'm trying to use something like this: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html but from what I gather it's better to define your view models as functions, so that's what I'm doing and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here is a nonfunctional fiddle of everything I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/MDNAJ/

Again, it lists all the results and you can click a result and get a popup with the correct info, but the search results disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one thing you're missing in your conception of View Models is the Object Model.  If you create an object model, then you can use it in your View Model.  Somewhat like in that beginning programming course, how you used a Class in your Main to do fancy stuff (aka "object oriented programming").

Your item would have a ItemModel, and it would something like this (attention to the OBJECT MODEL comments):

```
//namespace myProj
var myProj = myProj || {};
var myProjViewModel = {};

myProj.PageComponent = (function ($, ko) {
    //OBJECT MODEL
    function ItemsModel(data) {
        var self = this;
        if (data === undefined) {
            data = {}; //protect the data by creating an empty object
        }
        self.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
        self.type = data.parts || "";
        self.properties = ko.observableArray(data.properties || []);
    }
    //END OBJECT MODEL

    //KNOCKOUT VIEW-MODEL
    function PageVM(data) {
        var self = this;

        if (data === undefined) {
            data = {}; //protect the data by creating an empty object
        }
        self.searchBy = ko.observable("");
        self.resultName = ko.observable("");
        self.resultType = ko.observable("");
        self.itemsList = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.searchItem = function () {
            //ask server for items
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Page/SearchItems',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    searchParameters: self.searchBy(); 
                    //where searchParameters is a variable required 
                    //by the SearchItems function
                    //in the Page Controller
                },
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    self.load(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        };
        self.load = function (data) {
            //load Items into the ViewModel
            //which triggers an update for the observables

            //call jQuery map, which makes an array foreach data.items, do the function
            var mappedItems = $.map(data.Items, function (item) {
                //calling function and passing data: creating new ItemsModel, passing in the item
                return new ItemsModel(item); 
            });

            self.itemsList(mappedItems);
        };
    }
    //END KNOCKOUT VIEW-MODEL

    //PUBLIC METHODS
    var initModule = function (model) {
        //viewModel
        myProjViewModel = new PageVM(model);
        ko.applyBindings(myProjViewModel);
    }
    return {
        initModule: initModule
    };
    //END PUBLIC METHODS
})($, ko);

//put this in view
//$(document).ready(function () {
//    myProj.PageComponent.initModule();
//});
```